# Using jquery in place of watir or selenium for integration tests

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cucumber, integration-testing

I'm building a Rails app, and for integration tests I'm currently using cucumber and watir. I love cuke, but I wish I had something other than watir. Sure, watir's ok, but it seems like it would be more natural to test a web page using javascript. I would especially love to use the jquery selectors - they just make sense to me.

Does there exist library that supports javascript-based integration tests? Maybe something with node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered capybara + selenium webdriver? Here is an example definition of cucumber step, using capybara and selenium:

```
When /^I choose "([^"]*)" from scroller bar$/ do |arg1|
  element = page.find(%{div.x-picker-item:contains("#{arg1}")})
  element.click
  step %{I press "Done"}
end
```

Comment: I like that tool as well. But I was hoping there was some specific way to test directly with Javascript and with jQuery because I'm most comfortable with them.